# Как удалить несколько символов в одной строке одним методом?

Tags: java

Для того чтобы удалить ненужные мне символы в строке, я вызываю метод replace() в моём коде целых три раза. Есть ли более рациональны и изящные способы, как это сделать?

Мой код:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int len = scanner.nextInt();
        int[] array = new int[len];
        for (int i = 1; i < len; i++) {
            array[i] = scanner.nextInt();
        }
        array[0] = scanner.nextInt();
        String result = Arrays.toString(array)
                .replace("[", "")
                .replace(",", "")
                .replace("]", "");
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так попробуйте

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int len = scanner.nextInt();
    int[] array = new int[len];
    for (int i = 1; i < len; i++) {
      array[i] = scanner.nextInt();
    }
    array[0] = scanner.nextInt();
    String result = Arrays.toString(array).replaceAll("[,\\[|\\]]", "");
    System.out.println(result);
  }
```

Comment: Спасибо! Меня сбивает с толку эта конструкция [,\\[|\\]], где объединены все символы. Подскажите пожалуйста, как она работает?

Comment: Регулярные выражения. Почитайте много написано про них  https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Можно с помощью метода [replaceAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) и регулярного выражения:

```
String test = "a[b,c]d[,]e";
String result = test.replaceAll("\\[|,|]", "");
System.out.println(result);
```

Вывод:

> abcde